# Подскажите в чем проблема?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone, storyboard

Вообщем первый скрин- симулятор, во втором же видно как не до красилась таблица, заливал своим цветом. Может кто знает в чем проблема?( [image: симулятор iPhone 4s]
[image: iPhone 4]

В идеале - сделать так же как и на симуляторе

Comment: Так как видно линию сепаратора, она до конца доходит, таблица нормально по ширине выводится. Дело в UITableViewCell. Надо посмотреть, как формируется строка. Видно, что контент в строке сдвинулся влево.

Comment: Покажите кусок кода, как закрашиваете таблицу. Вы делаете ячейки прозрачными и закрашиваете таблицу? Или закрашиваете сами ячейки?

Comment: проблема однозначно uitableviewcell, в симуляторе увеличьте разрешение и, скорее всего, увидите ту же проблему, логично было бы менять цвет uitableview, вы же, как я понимаю, задаете его для uitableviewcell